# Internet connection drops during high traffic

Tags: networking, windows-10, internet

I have a 1 Mbps internet connection through a router. 
My PC (running Windows 10) is connected to the router via Ethernet.
When I download something at high speed (>10MBps or so), the connection drops, and I get an exclamation mark on the network icon, which says "there was a problem assigning an ip" or something like that. 
It will not reconnect itself.

The easiest fix I've found is to enter sleep mode, then wake it.

The problem appears only on this PC, and there's no problem with the internet connection on the other network devices.

Where should I start troubleshooting this?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

> 1. Go to Device Manager
> 2. Expand Network adapters
> 3. Right-click the offending adapter
> 4. Select Properties
> 5. Go to the Power Management tab
> 6. Uncheck the box next to "Allow the computer to turn off this device to save power"

If that does not solve your problem, you may also:

> 7. Go to the Advanced tab
> 8. Select the Speed & Duplex property
> 9. Change the Value from "Auto Negotiation" to "100 Mbps Half Duplex"
> 10. Click OK

See if that fixes it for you; it worked for me when my ISP made a change to my internet speed and I would disconnect from games consistently.

Comment: Regarding the first solution, there is no Power Management tab for me. I'm at the right place, i looked at some videos where other people do this, but it's just missing for me.

Comment: Have you tried updating the driver for your Network Adapter? it sounds like it doesn't have all the options available that it should. Can you post a screenshot of what your adapter properties window looks like?

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/xxMfujO have not tried updating the driver

Comment: hopefully updating the driver will unlock those other tabs; did changing from `Auto Negotiation` to `100 Mbps Half Duplex` help at all? you can still try that without changing your power setting.