# Internet connection drops at higher traffic - both on WiFi and ethernet

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet

I have a 100Mbps optical fiber connection at home that I access via the ISP provided Nokia G-140W-C router with dual band support (2.4 and 5GHz).

I have a Dell Inspiron 7548 (Core i7-5500U, 16GB, Intel Dual Band Wireless-AC 3160).

The problem is that whenever my download speeds reach above 7-8 MB/s and I am simultaneously browsing, i.e., whenever the traffic is high, the internet connection abruptly disconnects. The network settings shows "Not connected" to the internet. It is easily resolved once I turn off and on the WiFi in the settings.

My attempt at resolution:
First I connected my PC via Ethernet (I used a TP-Link USB 3.0 to Ethernet adapter - TP-Link TL-UE300) to see if it is possible that my wireless antennas are malfunctioning. But, same issue happened as the traffic rose over 7-8 MB/s.

Then I used a TP-Link TL-WN823N 300Mbps Mini Wireless-N USB Adapter to see if my whole network card is problematic. It still faced the same abrupt disconnection issue.

Whenever I use the Windows troubleshooter to resolve the issue right after a connection drop, it just resets the adapter and the connection is restored, just like a manual off and on. I also have troubleshooter reports for multiple cases. If they are required, please let me know.

It is worth noting that as soon as I cap my speeds at around 4 MB/s, everything works perfectly without any connection drop ever.

I have already tried to search the forums for a solution, but either nothing worked or the problems there were too dissimilar. A question that seemed a bit related to my situation was [this](https://superuser.com/questions/1450735/internet-connection-drops-during-high-traffic). The solution suggested there didn't work for me.

Now, I am unable to ascertain if it is my router that is creating this problem or my PC. Can someone help with this please?

Thank you.

Comment: Check your router setting, but it could also be the ISP disconnecting you.

Comment: 100Mbps is not optical fiber speed. I suggest complaining to your ISP, maybe their modem/router needs to replaced.

Comment: I tried to find something fishy in the router settings but couldn't.

Here, the optical fiber is in a nascent stage. 100 Mbps is the assigned speed for my connection. What's happening is that either the modem or the ISP or my PC don't like when I go over 7-8 MB/s.